# Python parsing JSON

Tags: python, json

I try to write a program that prompt for a location, contact a web service and retrieve JSON for the web service and parse the data, and retrieve the first place_id from the JSON.

```
import urllib
import json
import ssl
serviceurl = 'https://pr4e.dr-chuck.com/tsugi/mod/python-data/data/geojson?'

address = raw_input('Enter location: ')
url = serviceurl + urllib.urlencode({'sensor':'false', 'address': address})
print 'Retrieving', url
scontext = ssl.SSLContext(ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1)
uh = urllib.urlopen(url, context=scontext)
data = uh.read()
print 'Retrieved',len(data),'characters'

try: 
    js = json.loads(str(data))
except: 
    js = None

if 'status' not in js or js['status'] != 'OK':
    print '==== Failure To Retrieve ===='
    print data


placeID = js['results'][0]['place_id']
print 'Place id: ', placeID
```

When I am running the last 2 lines of code, I stumble upon this error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<ipython-input-67-55fd9f9478fd>", line 1, in <module>
placeID = js['results'][0]['place_id']
KeyError: 'results'
```

Could you help me to fix it!? Why this is happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Then you entered a non-existing location, I think. When I run the code, it works perfectly. Here is my output for the valid location `Wayne State`:

```
Enter location: Wayne State
Retrieving https://pr4e.dr-chuck.com/tsugi/mod/python-data/data/geojson?sensor=false&address=Wayne+State
Retrieved 2280 characters
```

Then  `js['results'][0]['place_id']` gives me:

```
u'ChIJ4Uny3H3vRYgRXPqO3llpGmg'
```

The entire `js` looks like this:

```
{u'results': [{u'address_components': [{u'long_name': u'State Avenue',
     u'short_name': u'State Ave',
     u'types': [u'route']},
    {u'long_name': u'Wayne',
     u'short_name': u'Wayne',
     u'types': [u'locality', u'political']},
    {u'long_name': u'Union',
     u'short_name': u'Union',
     u'types': [u'administrative_area_level_3', u'political']},
    {u'long_name': u'Wayne County',
     u'short_name': u'Wayne County',
     u'types': [u'administrative_area_level_2', u'political']},
    {u'long_name': u'West Virginia',
     u'short_name': u'WV',
     u'types': [u'administrative_area_level_1', u'political']},
    {u'long_name': u'United States',
     u'short_name': u'US',
     u'types': [u'country', u'political']},
    {u'long_name': u'25570',
     u'short_name': u'25570',
     u'types': [u'postal_code']}],
   u'formatted_address': u'State Ave, Wayne, WV 25570, USA',
   u'geometry': {u'bounds': {u'northeast': {u'lat': 38.2407197,
      u'lng': -82.43612209999999},
     u'southwest': {u'lat': 38.2390583, u'lng': -82.4396787}},
    u'location': {u'lat': 38.2407197, u'lng': -82.43794009999999},
    u'location_type': u'GEOMETRIC_CENTER',
    u'viewport': {u'northeast': {u'lat': 38.24123798029149,
      u'lng': -82.43612209999999},
     u'southwest': {u'lat': 38.23854001970849, u'lng': -82.4396787}}},
   u'partial_match': True,
   u'place_id': u'ChIJ4Uny3H3vRYgRXPqO3llpGmg',
   u'types': [u'route']}],
 u'status': u'OK'}
```

When you run it with an invalid location (e.g. `stuff`), then you don't have the key `results` in `js` leading to the error you get. Here the output (just the first lines) for this scenario (you then only have the keys `error` and `locations` resulting in the `key error` you observe):

```
Enter location: stuff
Retrieving https://pr4e.dr-chuck.com/tsugi/mod/python-data/data/geojson?sensor=false&address=stuff
Retrieved 10041 characters
==== Failure To Retrieve ====
{
  "error":"Address not found in the list of available locations",
  "locations":[
    "AGH University of Science and Technology",
    "Academy of Fine Arts Warsaw Poland",
    "American University in Cairo",
    "Arizona State University",
    "Athens Information Technology",
```

So, make sure to choose a location which is in the list of valid locations.

Comment: Thank you very much. I made a mistake when I type location.@Cleb